# MySQL Extracting data from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

First of all apologies for the newbee question, I am totally new to MySQL.
I have 3 tables with some fields. The relevant fields for the query are as follows:

```
table 1 - Registration 
user_name
user_email
ID

table 2 - photogallery 
ID
user_id
Status
photo_url

table 3 - photovote 
Photo_ID
status
```

I need a list of all the votes (1 record per vote) with explicited data of the photo and the user owning that photo. This means that Photo_ID in photovote is = to ID in photogallery and user_id in photogallery is = ID in Registration.

What I came up with is

```
SELECT * 
FROM photovote
LEFT JOIN (photogallery, registration)
ON photovote.Status = 1 
AND photogallery.Status = 1
WHERE photovote.user_id = photogallery.user_id
AND photogallery.user_id = registration.ID
```

But it really does'nt do the job. Anyone can point me to the right direction maybe?
Thanks a lot.
Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM photovote v
INNER JOIN photogallery g ON v.PhotoId = g.ID
INNER JOIN registration r ON g.user_id = r.ID
WHERE v.Status = 1 
AND g.Status = 1
```

Comment: I think the `user_id` of the gallery is the id of the creator/owner, who is a different person from the voter. So I think the first joins should be `photovote.PhotoId = photogallery.ID`. And you might as well use and `inner join` there, since there shouldn't be votes for non-existent galleries. The second join can maybe be an `inner join` as well, if a gallery always has a registered user linked to it. Inner joins are somewhat faster than left joins and have a symantically different meaning, even if they would probably give the same results in this case. Still a useful answer, though.

Comment: The query from @juergen-d works perfect thanks. Actually my mistake is clear in terms of syntax AND in terms of logic. Funny that he understood the logic fail of my query and replaced the condition correctly. photovote.user_id = photogallery.user_id is defenitely wrong as the first is the id of the voter, not the owner of the photo, also as GolezTrol stated correctly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT r.user_name, r.user_email, p.status, p.photo_url, pv.status as pv_status FROM registration r LEFT JOIN photogallery p ON (r.id=p.id) LEFT JOIN photovote pv ON (pv.id=p.id) WHERE p.status = 1 AND pv_status = 1